# Converting a string to an object reference?

Tags: java, reference, rmi

I'm using Java RMI to implement a client-server interaction and I'm using the client's object reference as a sort of identification. This works well if I perform something like *clientRef.toString()* to pass the reference as a string, however if I want to receive this reference on the server side how do I cast it back to a reference so the server can call client functions based on the interface? I'm using encryption so I cannot just pass the reference as a function parameter when calling a server function. I even tried putting the reference in an individual serialized class and passing it as a SealedObject, and then obtaining the class' reference and trying to call client functions but I get an IOException.
Is there any way to pass the reference to the server (not as a function argument)? 
In short (if I wasn't clear) the client reference is sensible information, just like a password, so I use it both as identification and for calling functions from the server. This is why I try to encrypt it but so far I could only decrypt it back as a String (by previously calling .toString() on the reference), or by sealing the reference in a SealedObject class, but trying to call functions with it gives me IOException...

Comment: You need to take the information from the String, create a new object and store the state specified in the String in that object. `toString()` returns whatever String the author of the class felt would be useful; it doesn't always contain information useful for parsing

Comment: Just to get a jump start on the confusion, what you call a "string" -- a variable of type `java.lang.String` *is* a reference.

Comment: What references do you mean? Can you show some code that explains what you use as identification?

Comment: Say if I have ClientInterface linked with class Client, I create my reference with Client c = new Client(); ... server.pass(c); where .pass() would take the reference. So the server can reference the client back with the argument from .pass(), so it can, for example, call c.reply("Hi!"). Client would implement .reply(String), which would be put in the interface as well. Now, I do not want to pass the reference as an argument (server.pass(c)) but I want it passed encrypted (server.pass(encrypted_ref)). My problem is how to get the decrypted reference back as I can't cast any object to a ref...

Comment: @VinceEmigh    Any tips how I could do that?

Comment: If you are the author of the class, override the `toString()` method and include the state of the object (field variable values). When you receive the String, create a new object and parse the values back to their original form. Also, whenever you get an exception, you should post the stacktrace for it. You aren't trying to parse the reference; you're trying to parse the object stored in the reference variable. The variable references the object. It doesn't make sense to parse a reference

Comment: For your custom [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) needs you may find useful Google's Protocol Buffers - https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-java-format/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works well if I perform something like clientRef.toString() to pass the reference as a string

Why? Why not pass it *as a reference?*

> however if I want to receive this reference on the server side how do I cast it back to a reference so the server can call client functions based on the interface?

You can't. Typecasting isn't magic. You didn't *cast* it to a `String`, you *converted* it to a `String`, and there is no reverse conversion.

Pass the reference as a reference. End of problem.

> I'm using encryption so I cannot just pass the reference as a function parameter when calling a server function.

Why not? *Non sequitur.* You should be using SSL in any case, not your own home-grown encryption techniques.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I can't pass just the reference _for security reasons_ as the reference itself is an _identifier_ (clients are identified by their reference). But anyway, I found my problem, it is in the encryption itself and not the data I pass... I just wrapped my reference in a class and serialized the whole thing to make it passable. Thanks for your responses!